# Using NASM and TCP Sockets

Tags: sockets, unix, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to teach myself some NASM x86 assembly using some Unix system calls. I am trying to create a simple TCP server and I have the code working up until the send() command. I can connect via telnet but I get a segfault once my code reaches the point where it tries to send a response to the client.

This is the segment of code that is producing a segfault:

```
; push on to stack for send
push    dword   0
push    dword   [start_len]
push    dword   [start]
push    dword   [socket]

; send something back
; THIS IS WHERE THE SEGFAULT OCCURS
mov eax,102
mov ebx,9 ; send is 9
mov ecx,esp
int 80h
```

Here is the full source code if anyone wants to look at it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
; constants go here
section .data
    start: db 'Starting Socket...',0
    start_len: equ $-start

; variables go here
section .bss
    socket: resd   1 ; store the fd for the socket
    socket_address: resd    2 ; socket address

; starttttt
section .text
    global _start

open_socket:

    ; print we are starting
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,start
    mov edx,start_len
    int 80h

    ; push values to stack to make call
    ; values go in in opposite order, so when they are popped
    ; it is the correct order
    ; below is for a tcp socket
    push    dword   6
    push    dword   1
    push    dword   2

    ; make call to open socket
    mov eax,102 ; 102 is the call to open socket
    mov ebx,1 ; sub call, socket()
    mov ecx,esp
    int 80h

    ; store the file descriptor for the socket
    mov dword[socket],eax

    ; this is the socket address to bind to
    push    dword   0x00000000 ; localhost (127.0.0.1)
    push    dword   0x2823 ; port 9000
    push    word    2 ; AF_INET (IPv4)
    mov [socket_address],esp ; move to our socket address variable

    ; setup parameters for bind call bind(socket, socket_address, 16)
    push    dword  16
    push    dword   [socket_address]
    push    dword   [socket]

    ; call subcall for socket to bind
    mov eax,102; sys_socket 
    mov ebx,2 ; subcall 2 = bind()
    mov ecx,esp ; push vars from stack to params
    int 80h

    ; setup parameters for listen()
    push    byte    20
    push    dword   [socket]

    ; call listen()
    mov eax,102 ; socket call
    mov ebx,4 ; subcall listen()
    mov ecx,esp ; move stack as variables
    int 80h

    ; now we have to accept incoming connections...
    ; setup the call
    push    0
    push    0
    push    dword   [socket]

    ; call accept()
    mov eax,102
    mov ebx,5
    mov ecx,esp
    int 80h

    ; push on to stack for send
    push    dword   0
    push    dword   [start_len]
    push    dword   [start]
    push    dword   [socket]

    ; send something back
    ; THIS IS WHERE THE SEGFAULT OCCURS
    mov eax,102
    mov ebx,9 ; send is 9
    mov ecx,esp
    int 80h

; function to exit the program
exit:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h

; main function to be called
_start:

    ; open it
    call open_socket
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using `int 80h` instead of just calling `send` and `recv` from the socket library?

Comment: `[start]` is contents of memory ('Star'). Likewise `[start_len]`. I think you want to lose the "[]" in both those places.

Comment: @FrankKotler This removes the segfault but doesn't return anything when I telnet in. You are right as it was looking for pointers char* not the value.

Comment: @greatwolf I am not quite sure what you mean. This is calling the send  command from the system call (102 subcall 9).

Comment: @Eric Your "port" only wants to be "word" (big-endian, as you've got it). I don't think you've got the "loopback" address right - I make it 7F000001h, but big-endian, so 10007Fh?

Comment: @FrankKotler I am binding to 0.0.0.0:9000 and I can see that when I do a netstat --listen and telnet is accepting the connection so I don't believe that is it :( Right now I can tell it's accepting the connection because the program hangs on accept() and when I connect the program exits after _supposedly_ sending back the data.

Comment: I am working on an answer to this question, but it may take me a little bit (I am experimenting with this myself)