# Should I store sockaddr on the stack with push or in the register for the syscall connect?

Tags: assembly

I started to learn ASM today for fun, and one of the things that I'm trying to figure out is how to open a TCP connection in ASM.

I've got the call to socket() down, because there aren't any complex data structures and I can just store the values in the registry

However, I don't know what to do for the open() syscall, since it requires a pointer to a sockaddr

```
    ; socket()
    mov     rax, 41
    mov     rdi, 20     ; AF_INET
    mov     rsi, 1      ; SOCK_STREAM
    mov     rdx, 0      ; Protocol
    syscall

    ; Valid socket?
    cmp     rax, 0
    jle     error

    ; connect()
    mov     rdi, rax    ; rax stores fd, save into rdi before moving rax to syscall id
    mov     rax, 42
    mov     rsi,
```

At this point I amn't sure what I'm supposed to do. Do I just push the values onto the stack?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you're storing values in *registers*, not "the registry." As for how to work with sockets in assembly, perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850082/using-nasm-and-tcp-sockets) will give you some answers. It's 32-bit rather than 64-bit, but looks like what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can always write the code in 'c', then generate the asm output and see how that looks.

Comment: Depending on the compiler, there are `struct` definitions in assembly. For example `NASM/YASM` uses `struct ... endstruct` while `MASM` uses `name struct ... name ends`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to push a `sockaddr_in` structure on to the stack, then set `rsi` to the address of the beginning of the structure.

I am not certain, but I think you will need to push `sockaddr_in` in reverse: the stack grows down but `connect` will expect the structure to begin at a low address and end at a high address.

If so, something like this:

1. Push long (32 bits) 0, *twice* (sin_zero[8])
2. Push long (32 bits) internet address (e.g. 3232235777 in 32-bit decimal form, which is equivalent to 192.168.1.1 in dotted-quad).
3. Push short (16 bits) port (e.g. 80)
4. Push short 20 (AF_INET)
5. Put value of esp in rsi (will point to short 20, which is beginning of struct)
6. Call connect

But I second an earlier comment: you could look at the assembly gcc creates for a small example using `connect()`.